# Connect to AZ VM from a non-ad joined device

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

> Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from Windows 10 PCs that are >either Azure AD registered (minimum required build is 20H1) or Azure AD joined or hybrid >Azure AD joined to the same directory as the VM.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows

My question:
Is it possible to circumvent this? We need to connect to the VM's from non-registered devices as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way as of now.

Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from Windows 10 PCs that are either Azure AD registered (minimum required build is 20H1) or Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to the same directory as the VM. Additionally, to RDP using Azure AD credentials, the user must belong to one of the two Azure roles, Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was hoping for, but unfortunately it's the way it is for now :) Hopefully this'll change in the future